# Is it possible to continue simplifying the given logical expression?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The expression given is:

[(P ∧ R) ∨ ~R] ∨ [ ~R ∧ (~Q ∨ R)]

The first law that I am able to do to the expression is the Commutative law, Hence:

1) [(P ∧ R) ∨ ~R] ∨ [ ~R ∧ (~Q ∨ R)]

//Commutative Law on LHS//

2) [~R ∨ (P ∧ R)] ∨ [ ~R ∧ (~Q ∨ R)]

//Distributive Law on both//

3) [(~R ∨ P)∧(~R ∨ R)] ∨ [(~R ∧ ~Q)∨(~R ∧ R)]

//Commutative Law on (~R ∧ R)//

4) [(~R ∨ P)∧(R ∨ ~R)] ∨ [(~R ∧ ~Q)∨(R ∧ ~R)]

//Inverse on (R ∨ ~R) and (R ∧ ~R)//

5) [(~R ∨ P)∧ T₀] ∨ [(~R ∧ ~Q)∨ F₀]

//Identity Law on T₀ and F₀//

(~R ∨ P) ∨ (~R ∧ ~Q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the absorption law, $A\vee A\wedge B=A$. Your last expression can be rewritten as $P\vee(\neg R\vee\neg R\wedge\neg Q)$ which simplifies to $P\vee\neg R$.

Comment: Interesting, you manipulated the last expression so that you can apply absorption law. I did not know that you can take P out from the parentheses and combine ¬R with (¬R∧¬Q). Cheers mate.

Comment: @KamarulAdha The rearranging of the terms is an application of commutative law followed by associative law.